# python, large ndarray append row in for loop

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

I'm working for signal processing using python.

I need process large mount data using one function.

I want to implement like below foundation

```
filtedSignal =[]
for i in range(0,N):
  filtedSignal = filtedSignal.append(filtedSignal,fft(signal[i],fre,N,B)) # it's returns ndarray
```

I want to insert every signal to one row.
so, I use `numpy.vstack()`.
But, in the first loop, it can not merged.

Any one can help me to solve this problem?

Comment: closing ')' is missing ..

Comment: Thank you for your mention about.

Comment: your looping from 0 to N but , but not using the i variable is there any reason behind this ..

Comment: It's just loop the data row size, and the result is add to filtedSignal. I will change the input.

Comment: filtedSignal = filtedSignal.append(fft(signal[i],fre,N,B))  try this or

Comment: filtedSignal = filtedSignal.extend(fft(signal[i],fre,N,B))

Comment: Thank you for your help. but it just need use filtedSignal.append(fft(signal[i],fre,N,B))

Comment: Highly suggest using nested lists for the array construction in this case, and then convert to `ndarray`.  numpy is not efficient at building arrays row-wise.  So `filtedSignal = [fft(signal[i],fre,N,B) for i in range(0,N)]; filtedsignal=np.array(filtedsignal)`

Comment: @DanielForsman Thank you for your comment.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. Could you add more information?

Comment: @kmario23 I just want use array like vector in c++, the problem has solved. thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are starting with a list; list append modifies in-place

```
filtedSignal =[]
for i in range(0,N):
     filtedSignal.append(fft(signal[i], fre, N, B))
```

Look at this list.  Does it look right?  Now try to turn it into an array:

```
np.array(filtedSignal)
```

List append like this is the best way to build an array incrementally.  It is much faster, and simpler, than any sort of array concatenate.  Keep in mind that list append returns `None`.  Stay away from `np.append`, which only confuses people.